# How to access Gravitee AM api

Tags: api-gateway, gravitee

How to curl the basic gravitee am api? i tried the simple one also cant?

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8093/admin/token -H 'authorization: Basic base64(admin:adminadmin)'

curl -X POST http://localhost:8093/admin/token -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5hZG1pbg=='
```

It stated 404 Not found. Result are below:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8093 (#0)
> POST /admin/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8093
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5hZG1pbg==
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to request an access token:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8093/management/auth/token -u admin:adminadmin
```

You should receive this payload:

```
{"access_token":"eyJraWQiOiJkZWZ......TyJ37E","expires_at":"Mon Nov 29 15:06:12 CET 2021","token_type":"bearer"}
```

Then you can use this access_token to request the access management API.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8093/management/organizations/DEFAULT/environments/DEFAULT/domains/ -H'Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOiJkZWZ......TyJ37E'
```